# Android studio keeps adding illegal line to R.java

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm coding an Android app and so I put a 0.gif image to all the drawable-XXXX folders. When trying to build, android studio threw an error:

/Users/ziga/Desktop/GimVic-suplence-android/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/zigapk/gimvic/suplence/R.java
Error:(28, 32) error:  expected
Error:(28, 34) error: illegal start of type
Error:(28, 35) error:  expected

After googling, I realized that this is caused, by this code in R.java:

```
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int 0=0x7f020000; //here is an illegal statement
    public static final int bg_card=0x7f020001;
    public static final int bg_card_green=0x7f020002;
    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020003;
    public static final int ic_launcher_web=0x7f020004;
    public static final int santa0=0x7f020005;
    public static final int smile=0x7f020006;
}
```

I renamed my image to santa0.gif and tried to build again: same error was thrown :/
Thew I tried to erase this line and build again: same problem occurred.

What to do??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try `Build -> Rebuild project` or `Build -> Clean Project`.

Comment: @Overv no actually I didn't. It may work so I will try tomorrow because I just went home :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when such weird problems occur, cleaning the project helps. That can be done with the following menu options in Android Studio.

- `Build -> Rebuild Project`
- `Build -> Clean Project`

Answer (score 2):

> I put a 0.gif image to all the drawable-XXXX folders

Resource names need to be valid Java data member names. Java data member names cannot start with a number.

> I renamed my image to santa0.gif and tried to build again: same error was thrown

If I had to guess, you did not rename all copies of `0.gif`, but only one.

Comment: I did rename all the copies

Comment: @ŽigaPatačkoKoderman: Then you should not getting the same error, as you would no longer have a resource named `0`. Please edit your question to provide the *current* error that you are getting, or find what resource you have that is named `0`. BTW, I filed [an enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78974) to try to get a better error message here.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + F (Windows) search for "0."
Cmd  + Shift + F (Mac)
You will find it if it exists.